# How to connect to VNets in Azure between different accounts

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

What correct way to connect 2 VNets , that each one sits in a different Azure account? is it using Virtual Network Gateway? 
I cannot make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a site-to-site VPN to do that. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal). Because they are sitting under different Azure Accounts you need to threat those as Azure to OnPremise.